# Aplicar estilo a descendiente en :onfocus CSS

Tags: css

Lo que quiero es que al hacer `focus` en un elemento `li`(usando la navegación con la tecla tab) se cambie el estilo (del `h2`, `h3` o el `div`) pero no me funciona.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```css
li{
 background-color: #361;
 background: #FF6;
}
li > a{
 background: #FF1;
 color: #1F9;
 border: solid 4px #F36;
}
li h3 {
  color: #a11;
}
li h2 {
  color: #1a1;
}
li:focus h3{
 border: solid 5px #21F;
  color: #a11 !important;
}
li h2:focus {
 border: solid 5px #21F;
  color: #1a1 !important;
 background-color: #111;
 background: #111;
}
li div:focus {
 border: solid 5px #21F;
  color: #1a1 !important;
 background-color: #111;
 background: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/articulo-77-fracciones-e-instituciones?fc=IV.">
      <div>
        <div>
          <h2>IV</h2>
          <h3> Metas y Objetivos</h3>
          <p>Las metas y objetivos de cada área de conformidad con sus programas operativos, así como sus funciones y actividades.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/articulo-77-fracciones-e-instituciones?fc=IV.">
      <div>
        <div>
          <h2>V</h2>
          <h3> Metas y Objetivos</h3>
          <p>Las metas y objetivos de cada área de conformidad con sus programas operativos, así como sus funciones y actividades.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

pero no está funcionando. Si aplico:

```
 li a:focus {
    border: solid 5px #21F;
    color: #1a1 !important;
    background-color: #111;
    background: #111;
}
```

Si me funciona, pero no quiero aplicar el estilo en el elemento `a`. Creo que no puedo encontrar el error.

---

Si yo pongo:

```
 li > a
```

en lugar de:

```
 li a
```

obvio *selecciono el elemento `a` que tiene de parent a `li`* solamente, pero en la segunda forma *selecciono el elemento `a` que es descendiente de `li` sin importar donde está en la jerarquía* ¿no? Parece ser un error muy básico pero no logro dar con él.

Comment: Realmente no dejas claro finalmente cual es tu problema. ¿Cuál es el elemento al cual quieres darle estilo?

Comment: quiero dar estilo al h2, al h3 o al div. A cualquiera de esos pero por alguna razon solo funciona cuando le doy estilo al elemento <a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por fin he encontrado la respuesta:

En efecto, como dice [error404](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/42663/23233), el evento `focus` no funciona en todos los elementos de html:

> The :focus selector is allowed on elements that accept keyboard events or other user inputs.
>     *referencia [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)*

Por lo tanto el evento acepta elementos como:

- inputs
- buttons
- links

Para forzar el `focus` se pueden utilizar dos formas:

```
<!-- "tabindex" -->
<div tabindex="0" id="1"></div>
<!-- y en nuevas implementaciones de html5 "contenteditable" -->
<div id="2" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Bien. Ahora, lo que intentaba era que al estar focalizado sobre el `li` cambiara el estilo del `h2`, del `h3` o del `div`. Ese era el principal error, lo correcto era cuando estaba focalizado el `<a>` aplicar el estilo.

Basado en eso, el siguiente código funciona:

```css
li{
    background-color: #361;
    background: #FF6;
}
li > a{
    background: #FF1;
    color: #1F9;
    border: solid 4px #F36;
}
li h3 {
    color: #a11;
}
li h2 {
    color: #1a1;
}
a:focus > div{
    border: solid 5px #21F;
    color: #1a1 !important;
    background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/articulo-77-fracciones-e-instituciones?fc=IV.">
      <div>
        <div><!--  tabindex="0" contenteditable="true" -->
          <h2>IV</h2>
          <h3> Metas y Objetivos</h3>
          <p>Las metas y objetivos de cada área de conformidad con sus programas operativos, así como sus funciones y actividades.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/articulo-77-fracciones-e-instituciones?fc=IV.">
      <div>
        <div><!--  tabindex="0" contenteditable="true" -->
          <h2>V</h2>
          <h3> Metas y Objetivos</h3>
          <p>Las metas y objetivos de cada área de conformidad con sus programas operativos, así como sus funciones y actividades.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

No funciona el evento `focus` en los `li` ya que estos no son elementos focuseables. En cambio, si que detecta el evento en el elemento `a` ya que este si que es un elemento focuseable.

Si quieres que tus elementos `li` sean focuseables (y estás usando `HTML5`) lo que puedes hacer es añadir el atributo `tabindex` a cada uno de los elementos `li` que quieras que sean focuseables.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
li{
 background-color: #361;
 background: #FF6;
}
li > a{
 background: #FF1;
 color: #1F9;
 border: solid 4px #F36;
}
li h3 {
  color: #a11;
}
li h2 {
  color: #1a1;
}
li:focus h3{
 border: solid 5px #21F;
  color: #a11 !important;
}
li h2:focus {
 border: solid 5px #21F;
  color: #1a1 !important;
 background-color: #111;
 background: #111;
}
li div:focus {
 border: solid 5px #21F;
  color: #1a1 !important;
 background-color: #111;
 background: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li tabindex="1">
    <a href="/articulo-77-fracciones-e-instituciones?fc=IV.">
      <div>
        <div>
          <h2>IV</h2>
          <h3> Metas y Objetivos</h3>
          <p>Las metas y objetivos de cada área de conformidad con sus programas operativos, así como sus funciones y actividades.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li tabindex="1">
    <a href="/articulo-77-fracciones-e-instituciones?fc=IV.">
      <div>
        <div>
          <h2>V</h2>
          <h3> Metas y Objetivos</h3>
          <p>Las metas y objetivos de cada área de conformidad con sus programas operativos, así como sus funciones y actividades.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: probé tu código en mozilla pero no produjo ningun resultado. Aún asi te agradezco. Note un pequeño error.

Comment: Revisé el reporte que enviaste y conversé con el usuario. Puedes revisar el chat [aquí](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51452/room-for-guzgarcia-and-luiggi-mendoza). Son cosas que suceden eventualmente. Si notas un comportamiento similar en otras publicaciones, favor de reportar para indagar más en el caso.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias @LuiggiMendoza. Todo aclarado ^^